# How to instantiate an interface typed object in constructor?

Tags: java

Consider this pseudocode

```
public interface Interface {...}
public class A implements Interface{...}
public class B implements Interface{...}
```

And now we got a class Container with a field of Interface type

```
public class Container{
Interface field;
...}
```

How to i make a constructor of Container so when instantiating field it calls correct constructor depending on whether parameter of A or B is passed to it?

Comment: `field` will be set to null, by default and interfaces can't be instantiated

Comment: You cannot instantiate an instance of the interface, you need to create an instance of a class conforming to that protocol

Comment: `B.class.newInstance()` will instantiate an instance of B if you really have the class B as a parameter. The whole looks a bit fishy, as a design, though.

Comment: If you already know enough to write `B.class.newInstance()`, then you could write `new B()`, too, which is the same minus reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Container` won't call a constructor. Whatever creates `Container` will give it an instance of class A or B.

e.g.

```
public Container createContainer() {
    final Interface myDependent = new A();
    return new Container(myDependent);
}

public class Container {
     private Interface interface;

     public Container(Interface interface) {
         this.interface = interface;
     }
     ...
}
```

One of the major ideas of dependency injection is that classes *don't* need to know anything about their dependent's implementations.

Answer (score 0):

interfaces can't be instantiated they are implemented.

just make a constructor that takes `Interface` type

```
Container(Interface in){
   this.field = in;
}
```

now when calling the `Container` constructor pass any implementation you like.

Answer (score 0):

> How to i make a constructor of Container so when instantiating field it calls correct constructor depending on whether parameter of A or B is passed to it?

I think you are asking about constructors for class `Container`, rather than for interface `Interface` (which cannot have any) or for classes `A` and `B` (since you pre-suppose that an object of one of those types is already provided as a parameter).  In the event that the static type of the parameter expression is one of `A` or `B`, you can achieve what you as simply by providing overloaded constructors:

```
public Container(A interface) {
    // ...
}

public Container(B interface) {
    // ...
}
```

On the other hand, if you're supposing that it is known only that the parameter implements `Interface`, and yet you want to initialize `Container` differently depending on which implementation is provided, then you should think again.  It is possible to do that sort of thing -- for example by using the `instanceof` operator to test at runtime which implementation is provided -- but almost any such mechanism is a manifestation of poor design, and in practice it is likely to cause you trouble.